# Mathematical induction in series

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, induction, factoring

How can you prove by mathematical induction that, for all positive integers of $n$ , $p(p+1)$ is a factor of the monic polynomial of $p$ in the sum of
$$
1^n + 2^n +3^n + \dotsb + p^n 
$$

I have got this issue when comparing the situation of $n = 1, 2 ,3$ and few more initial stages because sum of those cases can be found by other means. But I don't know how to connect assumption to the next stage of the proof. Your suggestions are greatly appreciated. 
When you consider $n=1$ the sum is $1+2+....+p$ and since this is arithmetic series answer is $\frac{p(p+1)}{2}.$ Here the monic polynomial is $p(p+1)$ therefore the result is true for $n=1.$
If you are interested you can further investigate this in the cases $n=2,3,4..$and it works. But main issue is what is the relationship between two consecutive cases, I mean such as between $n=1$ and $n=2.$ If there is a such relationship applying mathematical induction may be not difficult to this issue.
Can we get an idea by the help of Faulhaber's polynomials?
I have raised this issue because of my curiosity related to the pattern of Faulhaber's polynomials and I have come across many results in connection with these polynomials but couldn't able to connect with the mathematical induction. I doubt sometimes there may be a way by assuming for $ n = 1,2,...k $, and trying to prove for $ n= k+1 $
When you study the history of mathematics many concepts were formulated because of the skill of observing patterns. Therefore I think you can realize the importance of questioning this kind of issues .

Comment: It would be great before downvoting if you can comment on the issue why you are not interested.

Comment: @Damian thanks for editing because still I'm not familiar with mathjax.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no quality control on downvoting.  Also, there is a MathSE protocol **blind rule** about *showing work* that is totally oblivious about whether the OP (i.e. original poster) has actually received meaningful training on how to attack the specific problem.

Comment: The way I understand it, the asker (you) is expected to provide work $\textbf{or}$ context on their question. A simple statement like "I am self studying [topic] and found this problem in [book]. I'm utterly stumped and would like guidance to solve this sort of problem in the future." or maybe even "This isn't homework. I just want to learn how to do this." would go a long way to preventing downvotes. Honestly, I would have downvoted this if it wasn't clear from the comments that you were at least trying to ask a good question. You can always edit the question to show work or context.

Comment: @C-RAM thanks for sharing your views, actually this issue came to my mind because of the pattern of polynomials in cases available such as n=1,2,3,4 and this is not a problem I got from a textbook.

Comment: Ah, I think the issue here is it's hard to undertand the way you stated things in the question. How does "This problem comes from considering the small cases of $n=1,2,34$, and I'm curious to see if this pattern actually holds for all $n$". That makes it clear this isn't homework, and also lets us know that you don't yet know if the statement is true. I'll also tell you that some users particularly enjoy answering questions on small conjectures like this. An edit to add a statement like this might be a good idea.

Comment: Could someone please help me to use mathjax in smartphone ,  is there any app to download ?

Comment: Initially I did a great mistake by not sharing enough content of what I have done related to this issue that was mainly because I'm not familiar with mathjax. But I think now I have given enough information , hope you will give your fullest support to keep this question open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove that the $n^\text{th}$ Faulhaber polynomial contains $p(p+1)$ as a factor, for all $n\ge 1$. To do this, we use the following formula which converts normal powers to falling factorial powers.
$$k^n = \sum_{i=1}^n{n \brace i}k_{(i)}, \qquad (n\ge 1)$$
where $k_{(i)}=k(k-1)\cdots(k-i+1)$ is the falling factorial, and where ${n \brace i}$ is a Stirling number of the second kind.

The benefit of introducing falling factorials is that they are summed easily:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^p k_{(i)}=\frac{(p+1)_{(i+1)}}{i+1}
$$
Therefore, we use this identity to find the Faulhaber polynomial:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^p k^n
=\sum_{k=0}^p\sum_{i=1}^n{n\brace i}k_{(i)}
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^p{n\brace i}k_{(i)}
=\sum_{i=1}^n{n \brace i}\frac{(p+1)_{(i+1)}}{i+1}
$$
The upshot is that the final polynomaial is a linear combination of polynomials of the form
$$
(p+1)_{(i+1)}=(p+1)\cdot p\cdots (p-i+1).
$$
In particular, all of these polynomial summands contain $p(p+1)$ as a factor, so the total polynomial does as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach because first of all it's better to know there is a way to prove the mentioned result,  how to connect this method to mathematical induction is not clear.