# Find all integer pairs $(m,n)$ such that $\frac{n(n+1)}2\mid 1^m + 2^m + 3^m +\cdots + n^m.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can we determine the pairs of positive integers $n,m$ such that
$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}|1^m + 2^m + 3^m +\cdots + n^m=P_m(n).$

My attempt:

This is obviously true for $m=1$ and any $n∈\mathbb{N}.$

For $m=2$, we have

$P_2(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$
and since $(n,2n+1)=(n+1,2n+1)=1$, we need to have $3∣2n+1$, so that the property is true for $n=3k+1.$

For $m=3$ we have

$P_3(n)=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4$

Hence, the property is true for any $n∈\mathbb{N}.$

For $m=4$
we have $P_4(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n−1)}{30}$
So, we need to have $15∣(2n+1)(3n^2+3n−1)$ which is verified for $n≡1,7,13 \mod 15$

I am not sure if I should countinue like this, or there is a general method to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematical induction in series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570854/mathematical-induction-in-series)

Comment: @AnneBauval Not quite as the example for $m=2$ shows.

Comment: Oops I retracted my close vote.

Comment: It seems that for odd $m$ the property holds for all $n$ whereas for even $m$ the pattern is more complicated.

Comment: @user FYI, you're correct re: the property holding for all odd $m$. Using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bn(n%2B1)%7D2%5Cmid%201%5Em%2B2%5Em%2B3%5Em%2B%5Cldots%2Bn%5Em%24&p=1), there's [Let $k$ be an odd positive integer. Prove that $(1+2+3...+n)|(1^k+2^k+3^k+...+n^k)$ for all positive integers $n$.](/q/2018922) and the AoPS thread [Divisible](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1151091p5447456), both of which indicate this.